# ASP.NET View Page Validation Error - Could Not Load File Or Assembly

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I had a problem loading a .dll which I subsequently fixed - the application runs just fine.

The problem I am having is in Visual Studio 2010.  When I open a view page, the top line with the class details:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<TPS.Models.CashCarrierCoverViewModel>" %>
```

has a blue error underline, and it tells me that this old problem is still a problem, namely:

"Could not load file or assembly X or one of its dependencies.  An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format."

The original problem was x86 vs x64 issue - now resolved.  But this error still occurs on the view pages which means I can't develop with Intellisense.  This is obviously unworkable.

Most searches on this error deal with the original problem, not this Visual Studio error.  I've triple checked I have the right .dll, confirmed by app working, I've confirmed it's copied into the bin folder.  I've restarted VS 2010, I've rebooted the PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

The assembly that was causing the trouble was Oracle.DataAccess.  After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472341/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-oracle-dataaccess-markup-view) post, I decided to use the Oracle installer to uninstall the x64 and x86 versions (I mistakenly installed x86 first, which apprently caused the error to begin with).  I then reinstalled the x64 version.  I did a ReBuild, a Clean, deleted the items in the solution obj folder, then restarted the PC.  When I started Visual Studio it appeared to do some reloading of intellisense which took a few seconds after which it was all fixed.

Answer (score 0):

To truly 'clean' Visual Studio of all the cr*p you need to hit build then Cleans Solution, then go and find the **obj** folder in your project directories and delete everything in there.

now do a build-> build all.

Sometimes old files just don't go away :)

good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your help, mate - but unfortunately this hasn't done the trick...!

Answer (score 0):

Is your assembly set in Configuration Manager for AnyCPU platform?

Comment: Yes it is set for AnyCPU.  I have also tried to set it to specific x64 (which everything is), and it hasn't worked.  Thanks anyway, mate.

Answer (score 0):

You could try closing down Visual Studio and cleaning out the temporary asp.net files located in the correct framework folder in the windows directory on the c: drive.  So for instance on my xp machine it is located at

```
C:\WINNT\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\
```

Just make sure to clean out everything in this folder and try again.

Comment: What file or assembly is being flagged as incorrect in the error message?

Comment: It's System.Data.SQLite - goes with elmah.

Answer (score 0):

What I will try is:

1. delete BIN and OBJ folder
2. check "Reference" at right-mouse menu of the project "Add Reference"
3. check "References" inside the project at solution explorer
4. check DLL copy method and build destination
5. rebuild

Hope it works

Comment: Unfortunately, this has not done it either... Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0):

I will add this information here, even though it didn't fix it - just for anyone who comes across this problem.

[This link](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/556670/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-error-when-referencing-a-64-bit-assembly) pertains to the issue in question - Microsoft are aware of it, and it is uncertain whether the bug will be fixed for VS 2010.

So following the proposed workaround, I tried:

- Added both 64 and x86 versions of the .dll to the GAC, using Visual Studio command prompt and "gacutil /i [dll name]"
- Cleaned the solution, closed VS 2010
- Deleted all the temporary ASP.NET files

Then I reopened VS 2010 and the problem didn't seem to show up, then it magically reappeared.  I'm not sure why, but it may be a clue to solving it.  I will post again if I find any further results.